# Service not found error in Google Cloud backend service setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am trying to set up a load balancer following [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-serverless-neg#creating_the_load_balancer), but am having trouble setting up a backend service. The walkthrough has me run a command like the following:

```
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend my-backend-service \
  --global \
  --network-endpoint-group=my-neg \
  --network-endpoint-group-region=asia-northeast1
```

But when I do this, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.backend-services.add-backend) Could not fetch resource:
> The resource 'projects/my-project/global/backendServices/my-backend-service' was not found

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you create it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following this tutorial instead of Google's:
https://medium.com/swlh/google-api-gateway-and-load-balancer-cdn-9692b7a976df

That helped me set things up correctly. I think the clinch was that you need to create the backend service first, even though the Google guide does not have you do this.